# Nokia T20 not being detected steadily by Windows VM after clean-erased it while trying to flash GSI

Tags: usb, connection-issues, windows, nokia

I have a Nokia T20 WiFi tablet (TA-1392) that I clean-erased while trying to install an Android 13 GSI. The device does register as two different devices 3 times, each worth a split second, in my Windows 10 VM's list of USB devices.

I have done some deeper research and I found this tool made officially by the CPU manufacturer of the tablet (Spreadtrum, now called UNISOC) and is universally compatible with all Spreadtrum/UNISOC chipsets. The only problem is that once I turn on my tablet, it is identifiable by my Windows 10 VM 3 times as 2 different identities, each lasting a couple of seconds, before disappearing again. I’m starting to wonder how I can keep it awake while using this tool to flash the GSI onto the tablet.

Is there a way to install the GSI while unlocking the bootloader at the same time?